# Multiplying non-constant acceleration by a constant on every point - would the total path be multiplied by the same constant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, acceleration

If the non-constant acceleration is multiplied by a constant (on every point), would the total path also be multiplied by the same constant over the same time?
Both starting and ending speeds are zero at that time period (if that makes a difference, the a(t) is not defined as a function, but it looks somewhat like a sinusoid with t(start)=0 and t(end)=2π)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

If  a(t) is multiplied by c the integral over a(t)  and c*a(t) you can easily compare, the same with again taking the integral. So what is the problem?